# GCM with PHP: Unauthorized error in php function

Tags: php, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using the following code to send data to my device using GCM.

```
// Replace with real client registration IDs 
$registrationIDs = array( $regID );

// Set POST variables
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$fields = array(
                'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
                'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
                );

$headers = array( 
                    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

This works and I receive the data on my device, BUT once I put the code between function tags:

```
function sendMessage($regID, $message) {
//CODE above
}

$regID = "XXXXXX";
$message = "Dit is een test.";

sendMessage($regID, $message);
```

I have the following error:

Unauthorized
Error 401

Answer (score 0):

syntax error on the line , You forgot to put semicolon in the following line, change

`$regID = "XXXXXX"`

with

`$regID = "XXXXXX";`

Comment: That's not the error. I forgot to add the ; when typing this post.

Comment: did you initialize $apikey ?

Comment: I did, as i'm stating it works if it's not between the functions tags.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `$apiKey` variable is defined outside of the `sendMessage` function and is thus not accessible to the function.

You would need to add

```
global $apiKey;
```

at the start of `sendMessage`